# I faced a camera problem using in Telegram Desktop application

Tags: video, camera, telegram

System Information

- Manufacturer: HP
- Product Name: HP Laptop 15s-eq0xxx
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Telegram app version 2.4.7

  I can't use my video camera in Telegram Desktop App. `"No camera could be found. Please make sure that your camera is connected to the computer."` when I click on the video button.
  Everything is okay in Hangouts and Zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install Telgram with snap?
Then you have to connect your camera to snap:

```
sudo snap connect telegram-desktop:camera
```