# Make my external camera (webcam) as default for Telegram Desktop

Tags: webcam, camera, 20.10, telegram

I have tried the answer of this post:

[sudo snap connect telegram-desktop:camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293038/i-faced-a-camera-problem-using-in-telegram-desktop-application)

However, I cannot make my external camera the one which telegram uses in the video calls. I cannot see the option to select the input devices neither for the micro nor for the video.

By default, Telegram only uses the in-build camera of my laptop, but I want to use my external camera instead.

I have the last snap version of telegram and Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: I also tried this command but it does not work: `snap connect telegram-desktop:camera :camera`

Answer (score 18):

I have found the video call settings. It was a matter of selecting the default input video there. However, I think video call setting is a little hide in the settings menu.

*Settings* → *Advanced* → *Call settings* (in system integration section)

Comment: If you are having troubles to see the camera option (as mentioned in this answer), just remove (uninstall) telegram-desktop and reinstall it through snap using the following command: sudo snap install telegram-desktop

Comment: Damn, that *is* pretty well hidden. Maybe a > arrow would help.

Answer (score 6):

So, with a more recent version of Telegram Desktop (3.3) it's like this:

- click on the burger menu on the top left (the three stacked bars)
- click on `Calls`
- in the overlay click on the menu (the three dots on the top right of the overlay)
- click on `Call settings`

and from there you'll manage ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to go to *Settings* → *Calls* → *Settings* and I could select my external webcam there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on “FOUR LINES” in upper left-hand corner:
2. Click on “calls.”
3. Click on three dots in the upper right-hand corner
4. Click on “call settings.”
5. click on “output” or “input” to select your camera and microphone.